# Скрипт. Добавить убрать класс у родительского блока при клике по дочернему

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Вопрос такой: есть ряд родительских блоков с одинаковым классом `<div class-"block"></div>` (основных блоков) внутри которых, содержатся дочерние блоки:
 (кнопка <kbd>подробнее</kbd>, кнопка <kbd>закрыть</kbd>).
Нужно чтобы, при клике на кнопку <kbd>подробнее</kbd> к родительскому блоку приписывался класс `.active` (то есть чтобы получалось `<div class="block active"></div>`)

заготовка выглядит так:

```
<div class="block">
<span class="readmore">подробнее</span>
<span class="close">закрыть</span>
</div>
<div class="block">
<span class="readmore">подробнее</span>
<span class="close">закрыть</span>
</div>
<div class="block">
<span class="readmore">подробнее</span>
<span class="close">закрыть</span>
</div>
```

что пробовал:

```
$(".block .readmore").click(function() {
    $(".block").addClass("active"); //добавляем класс текущей (нажатой)
 })

$(".block .close").click(function() {
    $(".block").removeClass("active"); //добавляем класс текущей (нажатой)
 })
```

при таком написании срабатывает (ну почти), только класс приписывается ко всем блокам, а мне нужно, чтобы класс приписывался строго к родительскому элементу по нажатию на дочерний.

Вот тут скрипт в работе:
https://jsfiddle.net/UeML6/295/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `$(this)` и [.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) чтобы попасть на текущий блок.

```js
$(".block .readmore").click(function() {
    $(this).parents(".block").addClass("active"); //добавляем класс текущей (нажатой)
 })
$(".block .close").click(function() {
    $(this).parents(".block").removeClass("active"); //добавляем класс текущей (нажатой)
 })
```

```css
.block{
    padding: 5px 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #FFCA00;
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    
}
.block.active{
    background: #77EEC3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
    <span class="readmore">подробнее</span>
    <span class="close">закрыть</span>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <span class="readmore">подробнее</span>
    <span class="close">закрыть</span>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <span class="readmore">подробнее</span>
    <span class="close">закрыть</span>
</div>
```

P.S. Тут я использовал [.parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parents/), а то вдруг вы решите структуру поменять.

Comment: Спасибо) знал бы как загуглить, чтобы такую простую вещь родить уже бы сделал)))

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".block").on('click', '> .readmore', function() {
    $(this).closest(".block").addClass("active");
})
.on('click', '> .close', function() {
    $(this).closest(".block").removeClass("active");
});
```

Информация для самостоятельного изучения:

- [добавление обработчиков событий с использование jquery](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
- [поиск родительского элемента по параметрам с использование jquery](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Answer (score 0):

учитывая комментарии написанные выше, добавлю что parent у this это прямой родитель, и если у вас используется класс block c вложенностью в block, отработает не правильно

> рекомендую использовать прямого родителя, если он прямой, а не искать в родителях по классу функцией parents() и увеличивать расход памяти у браузера

```
$(".block .readmore").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass("active"); //добавляем класс текущей (нажатой)
 })
```

Comment: ну это я на пальцах описал чтобы вопрос было понять проще. Конечно на практике у родителей будет несколько поколений, так сказать) поэтому все равно придется указывать кого из родителей использовать